# Formatting the date on a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, simpledateformat, jspinner

I have a jspinner in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`. The problem is the spinner 'hh' only goes up to value '12'. How can i make it so it goes up to 24 hours?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have define for two things for [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) (basically contents of the tutorial fully answering your question)

- [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html)

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TimeZoneSpinners {

    private final String[] zones = {"Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Hong_Kong",
        "Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/London",
        "America/New_York", "America/Los_Angeles"
    };
    private final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[zones.length];
    private final SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[zones.length];
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private SpinnerDateModel model;
    private SimpleDateFormat format;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void makeUI() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setValue(date);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Date date = (Date) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].setText(formats[i].format(date));
                }
            }
        });
        format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[0]));
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(zones.length, 2, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i].setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[i]));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(zones[i]);
            labels[i] = new JLabel(formats[i].format(date));
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
        }
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        frame.add(spinner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimeZoneSpinners().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there's an initialization bug related to such spinners, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444308/jspinner-dateeditor-in-java-not-respecting-timezone-on-initialization). If you add a component to this example that snatches initial focus from the spinner, timezone formatting will be applied only after the spinner gains focus.

Answer (score 6):

The [JSpinner.DateEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DateEditor.html#JSpinner.DateEditor%28javax.swing.JSpinner,%20java.lang.String%29) component uses the same formatting as the SimpleDateFormat.

Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) formats.

Your format string should be :

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: To be explicit… Uppercase/Lowercase matters on date-time formatters, for both java.text.SimpleDateFormat as well as for [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). `HH` is for 24-hour clock, `hh` is for 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

ITS SIMPLE TRY IT.......

```
Date datenow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SpinnerDateModel smb = new SpinnerDateModel(datenow, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
SPIN_DATE.setModel(smb);
JSpinner.DateEditor d = new JSpinner.DateEditor(SPIN_DATE, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
SPIN_DATE.setEditor(d);
```