# How check the correctness of the month only after the second digit?

Tags: java, swing, date-format, simpledateformat, jformattedtextfield

I need JFormattedTextField which will format date ("dd.MM.yy"). Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter(format);
format.setLenient(false);
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
JForemattedTextField inputText = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
inputText.setValue(new Date());
```

The problem is: if the date is "11/06/12" for example and if I try to input 12 on month I can't do it because when I type 1 it understands the month as 16 and doesn't give me to input the next digit.
I need that when I type for example 12 on month position then the JFormattedTextField will check the correctness of the month only after I typed the second digit, and if it is incorrect the month will return back to previous value. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- maybe better would be to use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with [DateSpinnerModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532663/formatting-the-date-on-a-jspinner/9532721#9532721)
- you can implementing [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: Either if these is more reliable; also consider [tag:jcalendar].