# SimpleDateFormat parse for time

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

i need to parse a String value and get it as date object. Am using the following snippet

```
  java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("14:58:00");
```

My output is : `Thu Jan 01 14:58:00 IST 1970`

But what i need is only `14:58:00` as Date object is there any way to achieve this? If not what is the other way around? Please help.

**EDIT**
I need this way because,

I have a Jspinner(in a Jpanel) for selecting time in HH:mm:ss format . The scenario is I will open the JPanel to select the time and click on save button so the values selected will be saved in a variable(x).Now if i open the Jpanel again the previously selected values should be shown which will be read from the variable(x).

For this am using following code,

```
    SpinnerModel Startmodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
    StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner(Startmodel);
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("14:58:00");
    StarttimeSpinner.setValue(date);
```

On parse line am facing the problem. where i need only time(14:58:00) as date object.

**NOTE:**
I have tried the below code( it will work but wont allow us to change value again)

```
    StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner();
    Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("000000");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(time);
    StarttimeSpinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));
```

Comment: A Date corresponds to a specific instant in time, which includes a day and a time. So to answer your question: no you can't get rid of the day part of the date. You should explain ***why*** you want to do that because there probably is a better way.

Comment: for more info on what can `Date` object be, refer [Date Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: Your dateString has different format... `HHmmss` vs. `HH:mm:ss`...

Comment: @Betlista the code under NOTE is working as i used format(time), but its not allowing to change values again but automatically reassigns to old value.

Comment: This is an duplicity for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532663/formatting-the-date-on-a-jspinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").formatDate(date)` (you can use same instance of formatter) for output probably...

Comment: The op says he wants a "Date object" not a String.

Comment: _"But what i need is only 14:58:00 as Date object .."_

Comment: "But what i need is only 14:58:00 as Date object .."  I meant i need output as "14:58:00" and not "Thu Jan 01 14:58:00 IST 1970"

Comment: So, do not use date.toString(), where format is dependent on your Locale settings...

Comment: As am using a JSpinner , Date starttime = (Date)StarttimeSpinner.getValue(); is giving output like this "Thu Jan 01 00:00:39 IST 1970" so again i need to get 00:00:39 for setValue

Comment: read more here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532663/formatting-the-date-on-a-jspinner